# Pgfplots problem on vertical lines of discontinuous piecewise function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here I want to define a function that is piecewise, but discontinuous at some points.

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{b}{1}{\pgfmathparse{((3*#1+1/6)*(!(#1<0)&&(#1<1/2))+(#1+2/3)*(!(#1<1/2)&&(#1<3/4))+(-3*#1+2)*(!(#1<3/4)&&(#1<1)))}}
```

The plot is, however, a continuous line with some vertical segments connected the adjacent discontinous part. This is not a true mathematical plot at all. [image]

I searched for some relative questions but the answers were all about defining each piece solely. The reason that I insist to define them as one is that I want to make a iteration of this piecewise function. So it's more natural to consider it as ONE PARAMETER of the iteration process. I wonder if there is a common solution to avoid these vertical segments, meanwhile keeping the integrity of the declaration.

My Latex code is shown as follows

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{b}{1}{\pgfmathparse{((3*#1+1/6)*(!(#1<0)&&(#1<1/2))+(#1+2/3)*(!(#1<1/2)&&(#1<3/4))+(-3*#1+2)*(!(#1<3/4)&&(#1<1)))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2*#1-5/3)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines = middle,
                    xmin=-0.1,
                    xmax=1.15,
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
                    width = 0.8\textwidth,
                    height = 0.8\textwidth,
                    xlabel = {$x$},
                    ylabel = {$f(x)$},]
                    \addplot[
                    domain=0:1,
                    samples=200, 
                    %smooth,
                    color=blue,
                    ]{b(x-0.1)};
                    %\addplot[
                    %samples=200, 
                    %smooth,
                    %color=red,
                    %]{c(a(x))};
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no vertical lines in your plot.The function value is calculated in 200 x-values and between each resulting point is drawn a line. Your plot can easily be realised with a coordinate plot. Can you show why you choose to do it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not use your declaration, that you want for some reason, in your plot.

The function value is calculated in `samples=200` x-values and between each resulting point is drawn a line. PGFPlots has no way of knowing when not to draw a line (could be done with some heavy filtering, but it would be manual and ugly).

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{b}{1}{\pgfmathparse{((3*#1+1/6)*(!(#1<0)&&(#1<1/2))+(#1+2/3)*(!(#1<1/2)&&(#1<3/4))+(-3*#1+2)*(!(#1<3/4)&&(#1<1)))}}
%\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2*#1-5/3)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = middle,
xmin=-0.1, xmax=1.15,
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
width = 0.8\textwidth, height = 0.8\textwidth,
xlabel = {$x$}, ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot[blue] coordinates {
(0,0) (0.1,0)

(0.1,1/6) (0.6,5/3)

(0.6, 7/6) (0.85,17/12)

(0.85,-0.25) (1,-0.7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Piecewise graph]

**Edit - an other way:**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{b}{1}{\pgfmathparse{((3*#1+1/6)*(!(#1<0)&&(#1<1/2))+(#1+2/3)*(!(#1<1/2)&&(#1<3/4))+(-3*#1+2)*(!(#1<3/4)&&(#1<1)))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2*#1-5/3)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = middle,
%xmin=-0.1, xmax=1.15,
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
width = 0.8\textwidth,
height = 0.8\textwidth,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},]
\addplot[
blue,
only marks, mark size=0.4, mark =*, 
domain=0:1,
samples=400, 
]{b(x-0.1)};
\addplot[
red,
only marks, mark size=0.4, mark =*, 
domain=3/2:7/4,
samples=200, 
]{b(4*x-5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A graph with two discontinuous functions]

**Edit - an other way:**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{b}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(#1==0)||(#1==0.5)||(#1==0.75)?nan:((3*#1+1/6)*(!(#1<0)&&(#1<1/2))+(#1+2/3)*(!(#1<1/2)&&(#1<3/4))+(-3*#1+2)*(!(#1<3/4)&&(#1<1))))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2*#1-5/3)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines = middle,
%xmin=-0.1, xmax=1.15,
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
width = 0.8\textwidth,
height = 0.8\textwidth,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},]
\addplot[
blue,
domain=0:1,
samples=101,
unbounded coords=jump,
]{b(x-0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces same visual output as first method.

Comment: Much thanks. But for the same reason, if I need to designate all endpoints, I have to do every time during the iterate process. For instance, I want to make another copy of this function on $[1,3/2]$, then I have calculate some new endpoints again. If the iteration has to repeat many times, it will be a new problem.

Comment: In my solution, you have both the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` AND the plot. I do not understand, what more you want. Please edit your question to clarify. What does "this function on $[1,3/2]$" mean?

Comment: The thing I want to do is, using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` to define the piecewise function as f, and print a plot of the function g, where g(x)=f(x) on interval [0,1], g(x)=f(2x-2) on the interval [1,3/2], g(x)=f(4x-5) on the interval [3/2,7/4], ...., and so on. That means we'll have a copy of f of half size on the next interval, whose length is half of the former one. It's a process of iteration.

Comment: @user254428: See edit.

Comment: Thank you! That's great!

Comment: @user254428: No need to write thank you - just upvote and accept.